# SQL Trigger for record recycling

Tags: mysql, sql

I have created a MySQL trigger that was intended to clear out the oldest record every time a new record is added:

```
CREATE DEFINER =  `root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `cleanRecords` BEFORE INSERT ON  `Records` 
FOR EACH
ROW BEGIN 
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
INTO @cnt 
FROM cla.Records;

IF @cnt >=1000 THEN DELETE FROM cla.Records ORDER BY createdDate DESC LIMIT 1 ;

END IF ;

END
```

The expectation is to keep the 1000 most current records from a continuous operation. The operation is confirmed to be working, but this trigger is not. Am I misunderstanding triggers or is this one just incorrectly written?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/faqs-triggers.html#qandaitem-B-5-1-9):

> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger
>   can also affect other tables, but it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.

So you cannot DELETE rows in the table that activated trigger.

You should probably handle that in your application or use a process that cleans the table from time to time

Comment: This seems reasonable. I also noticed that I should have been using ASC instead of DESC. DESC was removing the same record that was being created because it was the newest one. I moved the logic to the application layer and it worked again. I will try the trigger again and see what happens.